# Move all files in subdirectories contained in one parent directory to N sub-subdirectories

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

So I have a directory with 44 subdirectories. Each of these subdirectories contain 15,000 files.

What I would like to do is: for each subdirectory, create a sub-subdirectory with max N files, i.e. 5,000.

From: Parent -> Subdirectory w/ 15,000 files

To: Parent -> Subdirectory -> **N Sub-sub directories** (with names starting at 1), each with max. N files.

Any advice on how to approach this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the code you have tried to make work. That is how SO works.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant to. Initially I had a lot of code that only worked 1/3 of the way, that I didn't think there was any point in including. In the end, I managed to find out an approach myself. See below for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of tinkering around with the unfamiliar world of PS, I did manage to code a solution myself:

```
$filesperfolder = 3000
$sourcePath = "E:\parent\subdirectory"

$j = 0;
$folderNum = 1;

$range = 44

foreach($i in 1..$range) {
    $path = $sourcePath + "\" + $i
    Get-ChildItem "$path\*" -File | % {
        New-Item -Path ($path + "\" + $folderNum) -Type Directory -Force
        Move-Item $_ ($path + "\" + $folderNum);
        $j++;
        if ($j -eq $filesperfolder) {
            $folderNum++;
            $j = 0;
        }
    }
    $folderNum = 1;
}
```

Which works really well for my situation! Each subdirectory I have is 15-17 GB large, and each took 1-1.5 minutes to process.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by iterating through each of the directories.

```
$My44Subdirs = gci -directory "Path_to_my_Main_directory"
```

For each of the directories, I would load all the files with an

```
[array]$AllFiles = gci "path_to_one_of_your_subdirectories"
```

Finally, you could use array descriptors to loop through groups of files.

```
$ctr=0
$maxperfolder=5000
Do
{
    ForEach ($file in $AllFiles[$ctr..($ctr+$maxPerFolder-1)])
    {
        move the files here
    {
    $ctr += $maxPerFolder
} Until ($ctr -gt "total_#_of_Files_in_this_folder")
```

I made this a bit generic so you could adapt it as you see fit.

Good luck.

Comment: Won't I have to do this manually for each subdirectory? Where does $My44SubDirs come in to play?